# free memory reporting when running "shark evolution"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this message:

I/Unity   ( 8132): Phone Stats - System Memory Free = 2019 Cores 2 Rez 1920

when I try to run Shark Evolution on my Android-L system. Apparently, there isn't that much free memory. /proc/meminfo reports only about 500 MB free. Not sure how the game ends up getting this big number. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It is probably `2019 KB`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask guys who wrote this game - what do they mean by this number... ;) This log print is done by the game scripts, not by the Unity engine itself.

The only Unity API I found that provide memory info is [SystemInfo.systemMemorySize](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-systemMemorySize.html), and it says

> This is the approximate amount of system memory in megabytes.

It returns **total physical memory**, not free memory. There can also be some plugin code behind that collects this number, or some magic, or... I wouldn't rely on this number until you really know what the game developers meant, and whether they really called systemMemorySize.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this does look like the total memory. I ran it on a few other boxes and it does seem to match up with the total memory